# Different ways to modify the created file time and date using linux command?

Tags: files, timestamps

---

Here is my created file using linux command.

```
touch tmp.txt
```

Now i tried to replace it date and time so what i did is as follows:

```
ls -l tmp.txt
-rwrx-rx-x 1 yush guest 600 jul 10 16:58 tmp.txt
```

I had used the following command to replace year for the above cretaed file?

```
touch -d "1 year ago" tmp.txt
```

Now,

```
ls -l tmp.txt 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yush guest 600 jul 10 2016 tmp.txt
```

My query is there any other command to do the above things using linux?

Comment: Why are you looking for another command? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly Set the Access and Modification time:

```
# touch -t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]
```

e.g.

```
# touch -t 201212101830.55 tmp.txt
# touch -d "2012-10-19 12:12:12.000000000 +0530" tmp.txt
# touch -d "2017-10-19 14:59:12" tmp.txt
```

You can use the time stamp of another file:

```
# touch -r file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: I think he was asking for a different command, not alternate invocations of `touch`.

Comment: @BobEager, perhaps, but I think this answers the only *useful* interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use archiving programs to do this (although not cleanly or easily). 
Note that the metadata
(permissions mode, owner, group, modification date/time, etc.)
of actual files (in the filesystem) are stored in the inode
(i.e., “system data”), but the metadata of *archived* file(s)
are stored as user data in the archive file. 
These can usually be manipulated, with various degrees of difficulty.

I’ll give an example with `cpio`;
similar effects can probably be achieved with other archiving programs,
e.g., `ar`, `tar`, `pax`, the `zip` family, etc. 
First, create your `tmp.txt` file with a known modification date/time
(for reproducibility); then create a cpio archive containing only that file. 
`cpio` options include `o` for **o**utput
(it means that `cpio` will be writing an archive)
and `c` to use a portable (**c**ompatible) format,
which may be easier to manipulate.

```
$ touch -d "7/12/2017 00:00" tmp.txt

$ ls -l tmp.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername mygroupname  0 Jul 12 00:00 tmp.txt

$ echo tmp.txt | cpio -oc > tmp.cpio
1 block
```

Check the archive. 
`cpio -itv` means read an archive (**i**nput)
and produce a **v**erbose **t**able of contents.

```
$ cpio -itv < tmp.cpio
-rw-r--r--   1 myusername  mygroupname  0 Jul 12 00:00 tmp.txt
1 block

$ cat tmp.cpio
070701000595CC000081A4000303E900030201000000015965668000000000000068E70000C36100
000000000000000000000800000000tmp.txt0707010000000000000000000000000000000000000
0010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000B00000000TRAILER!!!
```

I’ve discovered through reverse engineering
(it may be documented somewhere; I didn’t check)
that the modification date/time of the first file in the archive
is stored as a Unix time (a 32-bit integer
representing the number of seconds since 1/1/1970 00:00 GMT),
formatted as an eight-digit hex number at character positions 47-54. 
I have highlighted the value, `59656680`, above. 
Once you know that it’s a Unix time formatted as an eight-digit hex number,
it’s not hard to find. 
You can get the *current* Unix time (in decimal)
with the command `date +%s`, and you can get it as hex by saying

```
(date +%s; echo "16op") | dc
```

Now, to modify the metadata! 
Edit the archive with your choice of editor:

```
$ vi tmp.cpio
0707010005807C000081A4000303E900030201000000015965668000000000000068E70000C36100
000000000000000000000800000000tmp.txt^@^@^@0707010000000000000000000000000000000
0000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000B00000000TRAILER
!!!^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
~
~
~
~
~
"tmp.cpio" [Incomplete last line] 1 line, 512 characters
```

Figure out what you want to change it to. 
In your question, you mentioned rolling the clock back a year. 
Well, the number of seconds in a normal, 365-day year
is 365×24×60×60 = 31536000 (decimal) = 1E13380 (hex). 
So subtract  59656680−1E13380; the result is 57843300. 
And change it in the file:

```
0707010005807C000081A4000303E900030201000000015784330000000000000068E70000C36100
000000000000000000000800000000tmp.txt^@^@^@0707010000000000000000000000000000000
0000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000B00000000TRAILER
!!!^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
~
~
~
~
~
"tmp.cpio" [Incomplete last line] 1 line, 512 characters
```

Save and exit. 
Check your changes:

```
$ cat tmp.cpio
070701000595CC000081A4000303E900030201000000015784330000000000000068E70000C36100
000000000000000000000800000000tmp.txt0707010000000000000000000000000000000000000
0010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000B00000000TRAILER!!!

$ cpio -itv < tmp.cpio
-rw-r--r--   1 myusername  mygroupname  0 Jul 12  2016 tmp.txt
1 block

$ cpio -imuv < tmp.cpio
tmp.txt
1 block

$ ls -l tmp.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername mygroupname  0 Jul 12  2016 tmp.txt
```

and lo and behold: you have changed your file’s modification date/time. 
(`cpio -i` without `t` reads the archive and extracts files;
`-m` restores the **m**odification time;
`-u` means **u**nconditional (without this option,
`cpio` won’t overwrite a newer file with an older file);
and, as usual, `-v` means **v**erbose (display file names).)

Notes:

- You can get the Unix date (number of seconds blah blah blah)
  for a human-readable date with a command like `date -d "Jan 1, 2001" +%s`. 
  Use the `dc` (desk calculator) trick I showed earlier to convert it to hex.
- The cpio archive format includes null bytes. 
  The current version of `vi` (`vim`) seems to respect those
  (i.e., tolerate them and leave them alone). 
  Other editors, including older versions of `vi`,
  might corrupt such files (by deleting the nulls),
  or even refuse to edit them.
- `vi` detects that the cpio archive ends
  with a character other than a newline (“[Incomplete last line]”). 
  When it saves the file, it adds a newline. 
  Other archiving programs (other than `cpio`)
  might detect this as tampering
  and might refuse to honor the modified archive.
- Other archive formats might store metadata
  (such as modification date/time) in binary, and/or have checksums. 
  Editing such files might be more difficult than what I described here.

Comment: Fun fact: Unix time 1500000000 (1.5×10⁹) will be July 13, 2017 at  22:40:00Z (GMT) — a little over a day from now.